# General batch to move files between sub directories based on name not working

Tags: batch-file, move, organization

Creating a general batch that must run from the parent folder. It would serve to move...

> - PARENT\photos\Jan_2018.jpeg
> - PARENT\photos\Feb_2018.jpeg
> - PARENT\photos\Mar_2018.jpeg
> - etc

into...

> - PARENT\Jan_2018_Backup
> - PARENT\Feb_2018_Backup
> - PARENT\Mar_2018_Backup
> - etc

respectively

The final destination folder will always end with `_Backup`

This is what I have attempted and hit a dead end with:

```
for "%~dp0photos" %%A in (*.jpeg) do move "%%A"  "%~dp0%%~nA_Backup"
```

However I keep getting the error:

> PARENT/photos was unexpected at this time

PS: "`PARENT`" is not the actual folder name, but a placeholder for any directory that may be the parent folder to run the batch in.

Comment: You cannot specify a path after the `FOR` command.  That can only be used with the `FOR /R` command.

Comment: @Squashman Thank you very much. That clarifies a lot. I think I can make it work now.

Comment: Reading the help of a command helps a lot: type `for /?` into a command prompt window and learn how to use it...